# Alternative functions for proc_open in PhP?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I have a problem, i was using a PHP class on our shared hosting environment that calls wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF files, due to server attacks the Host disabled proc_open and shell_Exec and all functions that could cause problems if used by an attacker. All was working fine before the Host disabled those functions. In the PHP class that I use there's the method below that does not work anymore due to the disabling of the proc_open function. Is there any altenative that I could use in the place of the method below that will return the exact results? Any help highly appreciated.

```
private static function _pipeExec($cmd,$input=''){
                        $proc=proc_open($cmd,array(0=>array('pipe','r'),1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
                        fwrite($pipes[0],$input);
                        fclose($pipes[0]);
                        $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
                        fclose($pipes[1]);
                        $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
                        fclose($pipes[2]);
                        $rtn=proc_close($proc);
                        return array(
                                        'stdout'=>$stdout,
                                        'stderr'=>$stderr,
                                        'return'=>$rtn
                                );
                }
```

Comment: The way this specific function works isn't going to be possible without proc_open. It's possible there may be alternative techniques to achieve the same end result, but you'd likely need to replace more than just this function. But we'd need to know more about what the code is being used for to be much help with that.

Comment: Your only option is to submit to an external webservice that can perform these actions for you.  By definition your environment is locked down so you cannot call anything externally.

Comment: @Steve - do you know any web service one could you thats avalable

Comment: It would probably be more inventive to create your own on an external VPS somewhere.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few [services](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=pdf) available for this. I've never used any of them so I can't attest to their quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `disable_functions` setting can only be changed in `php.ini` itself, which means that it's server wide and applies to ALL sites on a shared host.

Here are your options:

1. You can ask your current hosting provider to move your site to a dedicated machine (or VPS).
2. Go somewhere else, find a provider that doesn't have these limitations; this takes some time, but might be worth it.
3. DIY. Setting up a server is not recommended unless you know what you're doing, but if you do, then any platform hosting provider will do; nowadays you can run a small dedicated site for about $5,- per month on Amazon.

The last option also buys you the option of "outsourcing" the PDF generation so that the rest of your site still runs on your current host.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I'm thinking of going for the last option maybe, creating a Web Service that generates PDF files and then still keeping the site on the old host. This way there wont be any issues eg moving site over, since it's a complex configuration

Comment: Do you have a link to the Amazon site where I could apply for a Hosting account

Answer (score -4):

Try use back backticks (``):

```
echo `wkhtmltopdf.exe test.html test.pdf`;
```

Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec().